# How to implement multiple view for single presenter widget

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I am using GWT-Platform and I read in PresenterWidget document that it is possible to implement multiple views with single PresenterWidget.

I am not getting idea how should I do that? Can anyone please provide insights how to so that?

Any working example will help better.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in gwtp samples (should be on github). Look at the carstore application.

Comment: @Andrei thanks for suggestion. I will check it. It will be great if you know it already than please share link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you can find a sample on how to achieve that, [here](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples/tree/master/carstore)
I believe their strategy is to group their presenters along with different GIN modules (i.e. Presenter X with view A1 go to GinModule1, Presenter X with view A2 go to GinModule2, etc).
Then they install one GIN module or the other, depending on some user agent parameter (in GWT you can do deferred binding via `*.gwt.xml` file).
This works well for them because they have this setup so they can have different views for mobile, tablet, desktop, etc, but the same presenters; therefore, the binding based on user-agent works well).

On another note, I think it is possible to bind through other mechanisms, but you need advanced GIN-fu skills here, and it's not really my area (but I'm fairly sure a colleague of mine mentioned this recently).